# How to move all hard coded strings to resource file in one go using Resharper

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, resharper, resx

I am new user of great tool resharper. I am impressed with features it provides specially localization.

However I am able to move hard coded strings to resource file. I wanted to know if there is any feature using which I can move all strings in one project to resource file in one go.  For now I have to click on warnings and manually start moving each strings to resx.

Is it possible? I am using VS2013. I got one tool "DT ReSharper Plugin" which works for VS2005 only.

Answer (score 0):

ResX Resource Manager extension for VS can simplify the process of moving strings between projects (import/export etc.) and managing localization itself. Take a look at its github [repo](https://github.com/dotnet/ResXResourceManager).

Installation: [alternative](https://github.com/dotnet/ResXResourceManager/blob/master/Documentation/Topics/Installation.md)

1. In VS > Extensions > Manage Extensions;
2. Search ResXManager and click install;
3. Close VS and wait for VSIX Installer to open;
4. Press "Modify" button;

[Usage](https://github.com/dotnet/ResXResourceManager/blob/master/Documentation/Topics/Usage.md)